# Can a supermarket be considered a yaoya if it sells vegetables in addition to other things?

Tags: meaning, words

Can a supermarket be considered a yaoya if it sells vegetables in addition to other things?

Comment: You got downvotes so you completely changed the question. What is the purpose of this question? If a supermarker in the USA sells vegetables do you call it a greengrocer?

Comment: Vegetables are only a section of the supermarket

Comment: I think it varies from place to place. In my hometown and if my memory is correct, yes. It's called よろず屋 (https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%B8%87%E5%B1%8B) ,but in the other part of Japan maybe not.

Comment: @kimiTanaka 八百屋とよろず屋はまったく別物かと…

Comment: @naruto リンク内中段には「何でもや、種々仕事に手を出す者、又種々な芸能に達する者、ヤオヤ（八百屋）と同義に用いることが多い。」と書いてあるのでてっきりどこかではと...。早合点？

Comment: @kimiTanaka その隠語大辞典の記事は、何でも器用にこなす「人間」を指す表現として昔「八百屋」「よろず屋」という俗語があった、という記事であり、これらが同じ種類の店だという意味ではありませんね…。個人的にはよろず屋はホウキや洗面器や裁縫用具を売ってるイメージです。

Comment: @naruto さんの解釈も一般的だと思いますが、https://www.jil.go.jp/column/bn/colum0264.html 内にも、「仮説その２　「八百屋八兵衛は万屋だった」」という記事があり、個人的な買い物経験から類似している印象があったので...。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. 八百屋 only refers to relatively small shops that sell vegetable and fruit. See this image search result: https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image/search?p=%E5%85%AB%E7%99%BE%E5%B1%8B&ei=UTF-8